# form doesn't return value (myTotal = undefined var)

Tags: php, forms, var

Newbie here working with a simple form that asks user to enter two ints and then adds them together and prints out the total. I've gone over it multiple times and it seems that my nuns aren't catching the numbers or maybe the ints are initializing properly? I'm not sure - i'm a newb and confused. Any help is appreciated (and yes i've searched for an answer via google and php.net but i'm not at a level that i understand what i'm reading well enough to sort it out i guess).

Code:

```
<?

//adder.php

if (isset($_POST['num1']))
{
    $num1 = $_POST['num1'];
    $num2 = $_POST['num2'];

    $myTotal = $num1 + $Num2;

    echo "<h2 align=center>You added <font color=blue>" . $num1 . "</font> and ";
    echo "<font color=blue>" . $num2 . "</font> and the answer is <font color=red>" . $myTotal . "</font>!";

    unset($_POST['num1']);
    unset($_POST['num2']);
}else{
?>

   <html>
       <body>
           <h1 align="center">Adder </h1>
           <form action="<? print $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
           Enter the first number:<input type="text" name="Num1"><br>
           Enter the second number:<input type="text" name="num2"><br>
           <input type="submit" value="Add Em!!">
           </form>
       </body>
   </html>

<?php
echo "<br /><a href=" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . ">Reset page</a>";}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using POST, you need to use GET

```
if (isset($_GET['num1']))
{
    $num1 = $_GET['num1'];
    $num2 = $_GET['num2'];
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks - i did that earlier on, but it didn't work which i realize now is because I had the some typo/casing issues. Thanks

Comment: No problem. You might find these two statements useful also. I use them all the time:
echo("<br><br>Get contents:"); echo("<pre>" . print_r($_GET, 1) . "</pre>");
echo("<br>Post contents:"); echo("<pre>" . print_r($_POST, 1) . "</pre>");

Answer (score 1):

Case sensitivity. Right here:

```
<input type="text" name="Num1">
```

But in your PHP script your looking for "num1". Remember, keys in associative arrays are case sensitive.

```
$thing['foo'];//and
$thing['Foo'];//are two separate values.
```

Also, your form is set to the default method, which is GET. Try adding

```
action="POST"
```

as an attribute to it.
As a side suggestion, you don't need to string concat your variables if you're using double quotes to delimit your strings. A double quote tells the parser that a variable could be in the string and to parse it as such.

Comment: THANK YOU! Being dyslexic those are always hard ones to catch; I've set the 'Num1' to 'num1' now. It's still not working though so i'm still scratching my head, but as least i'm one less error closer. Thank you.

Comment: hahaha no worries. These things happen ALL the time. I'll look through your code and see if there are any more issues.

Comment: Had another case issue, Num2, that is correct now. My vars seem to not translate from the url string to the printed page. Thank your for the catch on that! Back to scratching my brain again.

Comment: Can you post your edits in your question so we can see if there might be something else going on?

Answer (score 1):

PHP array keys are case sensitive, and HTML form elements are submitted with the identical case they have in the HTML:

```
if (isset($_POST['num1']))
                  ^---small n

           Enter the first number:<input type="text" name="Num1"><br>
                                                           ^---big N
```

since you're checking for the wrong form element, your addition code will never run.

Comment: I've corrected that now, but it's still not working. So i'm still scratching' my head on this one. Thank you for you help, one error closer D: Thank you.

Comment: PHP variables are case-sensitive as well. You've got `$Num2` in the addition and `$num2` everywhere else

Comment: Thank you - i've walked through the code again, looking at all the casings as I guess my finger was heavier then i thought it was, and i think i've corrected all the num1 and num2 and checked the myTotal as well. When i try to run the code, i get a url string that reads 'http://localhost/scc/sccc_2014/_240php/06a_troublshooting/resolved.php?num1=2&num2=3' but it doesn't print to the page (not sure how to explain it).

Answer (score 0):

You can also just change form to post method by default a form will use get.

Here you can see pros/cons http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp

i corrected the other case sensitive mistakes mentioned.
I'm learning php too but i put it together in case it helps

```
<?

//adder.php

if (isset($_POST['num1']))
{
    $num1 = $_POST['num1'];
    $num2 = $_POST['num2'];

    $myTotal = $num1 + $num2;

    echo "<h2 align=center>You added <font color=blue>" . $num1 . "</font> and ";
    echo "<font color=blue>" . $num2 . "</font> and the answer is <font color=red>" . $myTotal . "</font>!";

    unset($_POST['num1']);
    unset($_POST['num2']);
}else{
?>

   <html>
       <body>
           <h1 align="center">Adder </h1>
           <form action="<? print $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
           Enter the first number:<input type="text" name="num1"><br>
           Enter the second number:<input type="text" name="num2"><br>
           <input type="submit" value="Add Em!!">
           </form>
       </body>
   </html>

<?php
echo "<br /><a href=" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . ">Reset page</a>";}
?>
```